# Number of ways to packing $2 \times 1$ dominos into a $3 \times 6$ grid

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

[image]

I tried counting the different ways but couldn't figure out a consistent method, and would appreciate any insights.

Comment: there could be cases where domino cross the 3x2 boundary, so it's not a simple scaling factor there

Comment: @DonThousand:  Huh?  I don't see how one can "factor" the problem into three $2 \times 3$ rectangles as you seem to be stating.  Suppose the left $3 \times 1$ column is filled with $1$ vertical domino and $1$ horizontal domino.  Fill the unfilled squares in the $3 \times 2$ rectangle by two horizontal dominos, each of which extends outside the rectangle (to the right).  No factorization/separation/isolation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Never mind, sorry

Comment: There are $3$ ways to fill a $3\times 2$ rectangle and $1$ way to fill a $3\times 0$ rectangle.  If there are $a(n)$ ways to fill a $3 \times n$ rectangle then it may be possible to show that $a(n)=3a(n-2)+(a(n-2)-a(n-4))$; the $3a(n-2)$ part is easy.  Once you have done that it becomes simple: there are $3\times 3+(3-1)=11$ ways to fill a $3\times 4$ rectangle and so  $3\times 11+(11-3)=41$ ways to fill a $3\times 6$ rectangle

Comment: @Henry:  "$1$ way to fill a $3 \times 0$ rectangle."  Care to explain?  And what about fillings that extend outside the boundaries?

Comment: How do you get the forumula ()=3(−2)+((−2)−(−4)) ?

Comment: @Henry I think I see how you got your formula, and I think you should make it an answer.

Comment: @user526427 the $3a(n-2)$ is sticking a $3\times 2$ on the end three different ways, while the $a(n-2) -a(n-4)$ is replacing a vertical domino with two horizontal dominoes and building but you cannot do if this if the end is three horizontal dominoes

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a nice recursive formula for this, but supposing you hadn't heard of such a formula and didn't think of a way to find one, here's how you might count the ways in an only slightly more tedious fashion.

Numbering the columns from $1$ to $6$, we can consider four cases:

1. No dominos overlap columns $2$ and $3$ or columns $4$ and $5.$
2. Dominos overlap columns $2$ and $3$ but not columns $4$ and $5.$
3. Dominos overlap columns $4$ and $5$ but not columns $2$ and $3.$
4. Dominos overlap columns $2$ and $3$ and also overlap columns $4$ and $5.$

A parity argument (the number of squares covered by any number of dominos is even) shows that you cannot just have one domino overlapping columns $2$ and $3$, and you cannot have three overlapping dominos. It has to be two dominos or none.

You can also demonstrate that when two dominos overlap one of those pairs of columns, it has to be in the top two rows or the bottom two rows. Top and bottom rows quickly leads to a contradiction.

Another parity argument shows that in case 4, it has to be the same two rows overlapping both pairs of columns. Top two rows on one side and bottom two rows on the other doesn't work.

So for case 1, we have the grid divided in three $3\times 2$ blocks, with three ways to put the dominos in each block.

For case 2, we have two ways to overlap columns $2$ and $3.$ The rest of the dominos in the left-hand $3\times 4$ block then can be placed in only one way. But the right-hand $3\times 2$ block can be filled three ways independently of the left-hand block.

Case 3 is filled in the same number of ways as case 2.

Once you decide "top two rows" or "bottom" for case 4, the rest of the dominos can be placed in only one way.

Adding up the four cases I get $41,$ the same as the proposed recursive formula.

Comment: Just what I got... and by the same method (+1).  (I was drawing graphics to illustrate.)